# Search and insert if not found

Tags: excel, vba, copy, find

I have struck a bit of a road block trying to copy a row between two worksheets.  We can consider the first worksheet as the source and the other as the target.   If the `APN` field (string) is in the source but not the target we need to copy the entire row to the target.   In the `APN` exists in the target then only the 3rd column is copied.   The latter works fine, but I cannot get the copying of the entire row to work.  The `APN` field is located in column A and begins in row A2.  Any help would be very much appreciated.   The code is below:

```
  Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
  Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
  Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  Dim r As Range
  Dim matched As Range
  sourceNumRows = sourceSheet.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  targetNumRows = targetSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  Set r = targetSheet.Range("A:A")
  sourceSheet.Range("A2").Select
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
     ' Check for the APN
     APN = ActiveCell.Value
     Set matched = r.Find(APN)
     If matched Is Nothing Then
            'Insert row below at end of target worksheet
            '===================problem area===========
            'At this point I have a field in the source document that does
            ' not have an APN in the destination or target worksheet and 
            'so I need to insert the Active Row to the last row 
            'destination sheet
             '
         targetSheet.Cells(targetNumRows, 0).EntireRow.Insert = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
      '======= end of problem area============
     Else
            matched.Offset(0, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
     End If
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
```

Comment: This is [vba], not [vbscript]. I've updated your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps: insert and then copy the row values over. You've also got an error with your `Cells()` reference. You're passing `0` for the column, which is invalid.

Change this:

```
targetSheet.Cells(targetNumRows, 0).EntireRow.Insert = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
```

To:

```
targetSheet.Cells(targetNumRows, 1).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy targetSheet.Cells(targetNumRows, 1)
```

Note that the way you have this written, it will continue inserting rows at the *initial* bottom of your target sheet. Not sure if that's a problem for you or not. For example, if you add three new rows, it'll look like this:

```
╔════════════╗
║ TargetData ║
╠════════════╣
║ OldData    ║
║ OldData    ║
║ NewRow3    ║
║ NewRow2    ║
║ NewRow1    ║
╚════════════╝
```

Comment: Thankyou.  Yes I was aware of the reverse entries.  Although it isn't a problem but I was going to tidy it up once the essential code was working.  It works perfectly now.